# Sylvester-Gallai Theorem

Tags: metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry

How is this theorem used in applications? I've been searching for it on the web but can't seem to find. Only to "correct codes". Can someone please give a few simple examples?

/lost student

Comment: Do you have access to MathSciNet (Mathematical Reviews, online)? If so, type in Sylvester-Gallai, and see what comes up.

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth stating the theorem: for any finite set of points in the Euclidean plane either the points are collinear or else there is a line passing through exactly two of the points.

This theorem was probably not proved with any particular applications in mind.

Nevertheless, on my first page of Google results, I find [this paper](http://www.pnas.org/content/110/48/19213.full) studying higher-dimensional versions of the Sylvester-Gallai theorem. The abstract states that there are applications to error-correcting codes, and in the paper they refer to reader to [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.4375) for more information. It turns out that some generalized, modified version of Sylvester-Gallai allows one to bound the efficiency of *locally detectable codes* or *locally correctable codes*: codes where a given codeword, if corrupted somehow, can be recovered by looking at a few other words. I don't know how this works, but the second linked paper might explain it.